# It is safe to use constructors in function parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, std, tr1

This C++ code fails in Visual Studio 2010:

```
const sregex_iterator end;
for (sregex_iterator match(origString.begin(), origString.end(), regex(regExPattern)); match != end; ++match)
{
    useMatch(*match);
}
```

After the first loop, in the first iterator increment (`operator++`) the debugger fails indicating that the regex_iterator is "orphaned".

I noticed the dubious regex constructor (I copied the fragment from somewhere) and i tried with this:

```
const sregex_iterator end;
regex regexObj(regExPattern);
for (sregex_iterator match(origString.begin(), origString.end(), regexObj); match != end; ++match)
{
    useMatch(*match);
}
```

This worked perfectly.

But, why is the first attempt failing? I suposse it has to be with the `for` scope or maybe with the inlined constructor and the fact that the regex parameter in the iterator constructor is a reference...

But, as I read in stackoverflow some time ago, I remember only the things that I understand, and I would like to know if it is safe to use constructors as function parameters in C++ (without using `new`, of course).

Comment: Is it correct that you aren't initialising `const sregex_iterator end` to anything?

Comment: @Chowlett: Yes, that's the (unintuitive) way to create the "end marker" iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am thinking in the first case, regex is created as a temporary object and will be destroyed immediately after the initialization of match. It needs to have a lifetime that expands throughout the entire loop.

Comment: +1: It looks highly likely to be that regex pattern being destroyed (going out of scope) after the initialisation.

Comment: So, if you call a constructor in a method parameter, it has only the scope of that call?. That would only work if the method copies the parameter (or it is passed by value), isn't it?
And, why does the first loop works? It only fails in the operator++

Comment: One more thing: If you are right (and I think you are), the example in this page is wrong, isn't it? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

Comment: @JuanCalero: If you create a temporary in an expression, it lasts until the end of that full expression. So it's fine to pass a temporary as a function argument (by value or reference) *unless* that function stores a reference to that argument, and something tries to use that reference later. That's what your first loop does - `match` contains a reference to the defunct temporary.

Comment: Thanks @MikeSeymour, your comment clarifies the issue. So, the point here is that an unassigned constructor is a temporary that "lasts until the end of that full expression". This information it's hard to find, really.